# Reset AutoIncrement for all tables not starting with "_"

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I need to reset the AutoIncrement field to 1 for tables in the database. I found that this can be done for a single table using:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)
```

How can I run this for all tables except tables with names that start with "_"?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty risky thing to do. Are you REALLY sure you want to reseed every single table?

Comment: Yes, it is for modeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the next script for to do that. Maybe using `cursor` is not very performing but it is not take much time.

```
declare @TableName varchar(100)

declare cur_Cursor CURSOR STATIC
FOR 

  select  TABLE_NAME 
  from    information_schema.tables
  where   TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    and   OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1

OPEN  cur_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Cursor into @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  IF LEFT(@TableName, 1) != '_'
    DBCC CHECKIDENT(@TableName, RESEED, 0)

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Cursor into @TableName

END
CLOSE cur_Cursor
DEALLOCATE cur_Cursor
```

Comment: This will not work when it finds a table that doesn't have an identity.

Comment: All my tables has identity. Database normalization

Comment: @Akkumma ouch. Are they also all the clustered index? Just my 2¢ but that is not a good design decision. And just because they do right now doesn't (and hopefully not) mean they will all have an identity in the future.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, you are right. Thanks. I've already edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT 
    IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS Seed,
    IDENT_INCR(TABLE_NAME) AS Increment,
    IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_NAME) AS Current_Identity,
    TABLE_NAME,
    'DBCC CHECKIDENT(' + TABLE_NAME + ', RESEED, ' + CAST(IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
    AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME not like '_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the SQL query needed:

```
Select 'DBCC CHECKIDENT '+quotename(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID))+', RESEED, 0); ' From sys.columns Where is_identity = 1
    and left(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID), 1) <> '_'
```

You can either copy/paste it and execute it or wrap it into a cursor.

Comment: Thanks and sorry but I do not know what to do with result

Comment: The problem is that your query is not totally accurate. You can get some false positives with table variables with identity inside procedures and/or functions.